# Find a conformal map from the intersection of two circles to $\{z=x+iy|x>0,y>0\}$, the first quadrant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal map from $\{z\in \mathbb C| |z|<1\}\cap\{z\in \mathbb C| |z-(1,1)|<1\}$ to $\{z=x+iy|x>0,y>0\}$

I think that a fraction linear map might do the trick. But how should I find a specific one?

What is the general strategy for this sort of problem? I read stein, Barry simon's elaboration on conformal map, but they do not have any example for this sort of irregular shape region. Any reference on this?

Comment: _Complex Variables and Applications_ by Brown and Churchill contains a large number of examples of this type. (Separately, I removed the "complex-geometry" tag, since it refers to something else.)

Comment: The region is bounded by two circular arcs that intersect at right angles. The quadrant is bounded by two circular arcs (we look at the Riemann sphere) intersecting at right angles. So it's natural to map the points of intersection of the first two arcs to the points of intersection of the other arcs. Then see what that gives, and  rotate as necessary.